# ApiRest Beautify url with rewrite paramaters

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, rest, url

I'm building a RestApi and I have a problem with urls. I want to transform "api.php?request=users" into "api/users". But I also want it to be dinamic. For example: If a user types "api/users/13" I want it to be tha same as "api.php?request=users&id=13". Is there any way to make it dinamic? Do I have to create every case individually? How could this be done in each of these two cases? Thanks so much in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 4):

the best way is change .htaccess file like this:

> RewriteEngine On 
>   RewriteRule ^api/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /api.php?request=$1&id=$2&state=$3 [L]

The original URL:

> http://www.domain.com/api.php?request=mike&id=3&state=active

The rewritten URL:

> http://www.domain.com/api/mike/3/active

***update:*** if you don't know the number of parameter add one more rewrite for each 'level':

> RewriteRule ^api/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /api.php?request=$1 [L] 
>
>   RewriteRule ^api/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /api.php?request=$1&id=$2  [L]
>   RewriteRule ^api/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$
>   /api.php?request=$1&id=$2&status=$3 [L]

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, but the number of params is not static some times are 2 or 3 or 4 this example only works with 3 ( request,id,state) . no ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must add a new RewriteRule, because you need different variables.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ $1.php?request=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ $1.php?request=$2&id=$3
```